# Hibernate - SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet on Persist

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to persist an entity. When I use a native query to insert a row to my table it works fine, but when I use the EntityManager persist method to insert the entity I get an error complaining about the query as if it is syntactically wrong.

Bellow is my entity class:

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
public class Media {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "media_location")
    private String mediaLocation;

    @Column(name = "media_location_url")
    private boolean fromUrl = false;

    @Column(name = "date")
    private Date uploadDate;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    public Media() {

    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getMediaLocation() {
        return mediaLocation;
    }

    public void setMediaLocation(String mediaLocation) {
        this.mediaLocation = mediaLocation;
    }

    public boolean isFromUrl() {
        return fromUrl;
    }

    public void setFromUrl(boolean fromUrl) {
        this.fromUrl = fromUrl;
    }

    public Date getUploadDate() {
        return uploadDate;
    }

    public void setUploadDate(Date uploadDate) {
        this.uploadDate = uploadDate;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

I have my manager class as bellow:

```
@Stateless
public class UserManager {

    @EJB
    private BaseDao baseDao;

    public String createNewMedia_test() {

        Media media = new Media();
        media.setFromUrl(false);
        media.setDescription("adsddfsd");
        media.setMediaLocation("here");
        media.setUploadDate(new Date());

        baseDao.saveMedia(media);

        return "OK";

    }
}
```

And BaseDao is as bellow :

```
@Stateless
public class BaseDao {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName="MySqlDS")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public void saveMedia(Media media) {

        entityManager.persist(media);
    }
}
```

But it's upon the persist call that I get the error, in my localhost web ui I see the stack trace starting with

```
Query String:null
Stack Trace
javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
```

Comment: Could you set the Hibernate property `hibernate.show_sql` to true, then look at the query being executed.

Comment: Where should I specify this?

Comment: In your persistence.xml config file, see  https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/configuration.html

Comment: I can see the queries now. But upon executing the persist, all is printed in the consol is
Hibernate: 
 call next value for hibernate_sequence
and then the errors and stacktrace appears.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to call `persist()` within a Hibernate *transaction*.  Try wrapping your call to `persist()` inside a transaction as in the following code snippet:

```
@Stateless
public class BaseDao {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName="MySqlDS")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public void saveMedia(Media media) {

        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        entityManager.persist(media);
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
    }
}
```